# Has a corpus-based unprofessional bilingual dictionary ever been written - how was it received?

Tags: english, dictionary, writing, german

I am thinking of compiling a **bilingual dictionary** (German-English for that matter, but the question may be generalized).

I was thinking of using a specific and finite **corpus of texts**, which should be large enough to provide rather many terms and examples. Let's say I will be using the Bible as my source (I won't, just for the sake of discussion). That means the dictionary will not be as comprehensive as possible (others have done that already); rather, it will be another German-English dictionary with a certain "character" to it since it will be based on a defined corpus and will provide definitions for German words (I will gather the definitions from existing dictionaries) and examples from that corpus.

Have other people done similar things in German or other languages? If so, how was this received?

Note: "Unprofessional" here means that the dictionary is/was compiled by someone who was not trained in linguistics.

Comment: And why would we need another dictionary? What would make your dictionary special?

Comment: Well, it won't be that special really,@AlexB. I planned on compiling this dictionary for my own use, as an exercise and to get more exposure to German-English translation in a rather methodological way. Then I pondered whether this might help other people to learn the language, especially if the examples are taken from a certain corpus in which some people may find interest - obviously it could help, and would certainly not do harm, but I wanted to see what the expert community has to say about such an idea. I actually started working on it, but it seems more difficult than I thought...

Comment: It should be (difficult). Good luck anyway!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dictionary creators who are not trained in linguistics or lexicography are in good company.

[**Samuel Johnson**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samuel_Johnson) (1709-1784) created his **[*A Dictionary of the English Language*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Dictionary_of_the_English_Language)** between the years 1746 and 1755 (year of publication). Johnson was not trained in linguistics or lexicography; he never finished university because he ran out of money.

Johnson used hundreds of books (his "corpus") as sources for quotations or example sentences. His dictionary contained approximately 114,000 literary quotations (Shakespeare, Milton, Dryden, etc.). Johnson's dictionary remained the most influential English dictionary until the completion of the [*Oxford English Dictionary*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxford_English_Dictionary) or OED in 1928 (the first volume of the OED was published in 1888). In addition, as Michael Adams wrote, **[Johnson made dictionaries matter](https://www.neh.gov/humanities/2009/septemberoctober/feature/what-samuel-johnson-really-did)**.

The original authors of the **[*Deutsches Wörterbuch*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsches_W%C3%B6rterbuch)**, [Jacob Grimm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacob_Grimm) (1785-1863) and his younger brother [Wilhelm Grimm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilhelm_Grimm) (1786-1859) both studied law, not linguistics or lexicography, at the University of Marburg. Their dictionary also uses quotations. The *Deutsches Wörterbuch* is to the German language what the *OED* is to the English language.

The above are *monolingual* dictionaries, so I have only proven that *unprofessional monolingual dictionaries* have been produced in the past. 
I should also give at least one example of a bilingual dictionary.

The Italian **[Giovanni Florio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Florio)** (1553-1625, better known as John Florio) was a language tutor at the court of James I of England but was not trained as a linguist or a lexicographer. In 1598 he published an Italian-English dictionary entitled *A World of Words*, which he expanded and republished in 1611 under the title *Queen Anna's New World of Words, or Dictionarie of the Italian and English tongues, Collected, and newly much augmented by Iohn Florio, Reader of the Italian vnto the Soueraigne Maiestie of Anna, Crowned Queene of England, Scotland, France and Ireland, &c. And one of the Gentlemen of hir Royall Priuie Chamber. Whereunto are added certaine necessarie rules and short obseruations for the Italian tongue.* The dictionary uses quotations, though not for all entries. (It is not clear what Florio's *corpus* would have been.) Both versions of the dictionary can be downloaded [Greg Lindahl's website](http://www.pbm.com/~lindahl/florio/), who also provided a [searchable version](http://www.pbm.com/~lindahl/florio/search/search.cgi).

[**Ambrogio Calepino**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambrogio_Calepino) (c. 1440–1510) wrote a Latin dictionary that was first published in 1502. It cited classical sources. Later, in the 1580s, Jesuits in Japan used it as a basis for the *Dictionarium Latino Lusitanicum, ac Iaponicum* (DLLI), a Latin-Portuguese-Japanese dictionary, which retained only part of the quotes from classical authors. See Emi Kishimoto: [Annotations in *Dictionarium Latino Lusitanicum, ac Iaponicum* (1595) in the Context of Latin Education by the Jesuits in Japan](http://www.euralex.org/elx_proceedings/Euralex2010/094_Euralex_2010_6_KISHIMOTO_Annotations%20in%20Dictionarium%20Latino%20Lusitanicum,%20ac%20Iaponicum%201595%20in%20the%20Context%20of%20Latin%20E.pdf) (PDF).

Update:

- Smadja, Frank: [How to Compile a Bilingual Collocational Lexicon Automaticall](http://www.aaai.org/Papers/Workshops/1992/WS-92-01/WS92-01-007.pdf), AAAI Technical Report WS-92-01, 1992. (Uses statistical techniques to create an English-French lexicon based on a bilingual corpus.)

Comment: The discipline that deals with creating dictionaries is lexicography, not linguistics. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicography), "[i]t is now widely accepted that lexicography is a scholarly discipline in its own right and not a sub-branch of applied linguistics, as the chief object of study in lexicography is the dictionary (see e.g. Bergenholtz/Nielsen/Tarp 2009).". So it would be relevant to say whether these people were trained as lexicographers.

Comment: By the way, the word "lexicography" [was coined in 1680](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicography) and "linguistics" in [the 19th century](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/160220/which-is-the-older-sense-of-the-word-linguist). Nobody was really trained as a linguist before that time, and at the time of Florio there was not even "philology".

Comment: @michau The phenomenon of lexicography predates the invention of the word "lexicography", just like gravitation predates the invention of the term "gravitation" ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a good one, expressing an interest in compiling a German-English dictionary.

Firstly, as you already recognize, all dictionaries are based on a selected body of texts, or *corpus*, as you put it.  Your idea, like other dictionary writers, necessarily requires limiting the number, topics, and style of your *corpus*.  And, if I'm correct, you want to draw from your *corpus* topical words that will *characterize* your dictionary.

Now, since cookbooks of all types are the largest sellers in both books and mortar and online bookstores, and ethnic cookbooks sell quite well, have you thought of perhaps starting out on your project idea by compiling a small German-English cookbook dictionary of German cooking terms as a trial project?

The tie-in here to your dictionary idea is that German language cookbooks are available on the German Amazon website (www.Amazon.de); you could build the corpus for a German-English cookbook dictionary from a small sampling of German language cookbooks bought through the German Amazon.  And of course a cookbook dictionary would add flavor and character to your dictionary, and differentiate it from other dictionaries.

So with these few words of advice may you have success in your carrying out your idea.

Comment: Your answer would benefit from more specific references. Any ISBN or URL maybe?

Comment: I just happen to collect old and very old cookbooks.  My oldest cookbook is "Praktisches Kochbuch für die Deutschen in Amerika".  The cookbook has no publication date, but it does have the dated inscription "Katie Blattert  1887".  The cookbook is 400 pages of dense Gothic type;  I do my translations of German recipes and home remedies using my two part 1936 (German)/1939 (English) "Cassell's New German and English Dictionary" where the German language therein is also in Gothic font.  I wou

Comment: Please [edit](http://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/posts/2478/edit) your answer instead of adding details as comments. Comments are often removed.

Comment: [con't] I would dearly love to have a bilingual German-English dictionary consisting only of German culinary terms that I could quickly use instead of having to  wade through page after page of Cassell's  multi-corpus dictionaries.  A more comprehensive source than Amazon is Google.de.  That website yields many hits for "kochbuch", including hits showing vendors who sell a German-language kochbuch for the contemporary game "Game of Thrones" kochbuch.  Useful perhaps for Don_S as an inclusion in his trial corpus.  As for ISBN's, "Google the book" 's the best answer; anyone can do that.

Comment: bytebuster:  Thanks for your two worthwhile  comments.  Firstly, I prefer to put my off-topic remarks in a comment instead of cluttering up my answer with off-topic stuff.  So what if some community  'cockroach' doesn't like my comments and deletes them.  As in the lyrics of an old 60's-era pop songSecondly, my response re: ISBN's and URL's was curt because I could see the bottom of my bag of comment characters, and I was running out of them.

Comment: There!  I've done it again! Hit a CR when I shouldn't have. Anyway, the 50's-era song I was referring to (it was actually a 50's-era song) was "Gonna' Get Along Without You".  So I just refer in German to those website cockroaches in the same vein as that song, "Das macht nichts".  Such deletions mean nothing to me ... unless I've clearly violated the SE website's Community Standards.

Comment: Please be aware [how comments work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work): "Comments are often used to ask for clarification on, suggest corrections to and provide meta-information about posts. (...) Comments are disposable: unlike posts, there's no revision history, and they can be deleted without warning by their authors, by moderators, and in response to flags." Normal users can remove only their own comments; only moderators can remove other people's comments. Their removal has nothing to do with bad faith or what you call "website cockroaches".

Comment: Please note that all my comments herein relate directly to the user's question and his sub-questions.